# classList.contains("active") returns false OR error. never true

Tags: javascript

I'm having a strange issue here, I have an app with a div that has a click event attached to all inner elements, and when a div is clicked it adds a class "active" when I log

```
console.log(element.classList.contains("active"));
```

every element that HAS the active class errors and the ones that don't return "false"

E.G. HTML:

```
<div class="kick">
  <div class="pads kick-pad p0"></div>
  <div class="pads kick-pad p1 active"></div>
  <div class="pads kick-pad p2"></div>
  <div class="pads kick-pad p3 active"></div>
  <div class="pads kick-pad p4"></div>
  <div class="pads kick-pad p5"></div>
  <div class="pads kick-pad p6"></div>
  <div class="pads kick-pad p7"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: the error: "Uncaught TypeError: element.classList.contains is not a function"
2nd Edit: I should add that

```
console.log(element.classList);
```

returns a single element with all the classes on it, including active. it only errors with the ".contains" method

3rd Edit: https://codepen.io/ruination/pen/qBZyVpQ

to clarify:

1. the elements are the correct elements and have the correct class but it doesn't return true OR false, only the error: "Uncaught TypeError: element.classList.contains is not a function"
2. it DOES return false when the elements don't have the class "active" though.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: If you have correctly chosen your element (also important that its a single element, not a list) then it should return either true or false. It would help if you show the error and how you've selected your element.

Comment: The code that you are providing does not produce the error. How are you selecting the element?

Comment: copy/paste this code into codepen.io... this code works. the error is I don't think element is what you think it is. console log element?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Judging by your code and that the unknown part is how you select the element, I assume that's where the problem is.

For example, on this page, if you open the console and select the question element and check if it has a class as such:

```
document.querySelector('#question-header').classList.contains('grid');
```

It will return `true`

And if you do:

```
document.querySelector('#question-header').classList.contains('gri');
```

It will return `false`

As simple as that. Make sure before you check for a class, see if the `element` variable does have the correct element you want. Debugging before that point might also help.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the elements in question are the correct elements and have the correct class but it doesn't  return true or false, only the error. it DOES return false when the elements don't have the class though.

Comment: I've found the issue. Inside your event listener where you're listening to kit.tracks clicks, you're overriding the classList's contains method by setting it to a string, in this case, "pads", in line 56. Just changing the assignment operator = to triple equals, to check value, will solve your problem.

Comment: Wow thanks! this was helpful! the triple equals didn't work but I used brackets instead and it works like a charm thanks!!